# Static class member declaration error

Tags: c++

I am trying to find dynamically and statically instantiated objects number.  I am getting errors that variable myheap is not declared.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

class A {
public:
  static int x;   //To count number of total objects. incremented in constructor
  static int myheap;  //To count number of heap objects. Incremented in overloaded new

  void* operator new(size_t t) {
    A *p;
    p=(A*)malloc(t);
    myheap++;
    return p;
  }

  void operator delete(void *p) {
    free(p);
    myheap--;
  }

  A() {
    x++;
  }

  ~A() {
    x--;
  }
};
int A::x=0;
int A::myheap=0;

int main() {
  A *g,*h,*i;
  A a,c,b,d,e;//Static allocations 5

  g= new A();//Dynamic allocations 3
  h= new A();
  i= new A();

  cout<<"Total"<<A::x<<'\n';

  cout<<"Dynamic";
  cout<<'\n'<<"HEAP"<<A::myheap;

  delete g;
  cout<<'\n'<<"After delete g"<<A::x;
  cout<<'\n'<<"HEAP"<<A::myheap;
  delete h;
  cout<<'\n'<<"After delete h"<<A::x;
  cout<<'\n'<<"HEAP"<<A::myheap;
  delete i;
  cout<<'\n'<<"After delete i"<<A::x;
  cout<<'\n'<<"HEAP"<<A::myheap;
}
```

Comment: After fixing myheap to A::myheap it worked. I have updated the code and its working. Thanks all

When i was not returning p from new, it was giving warning and compiled. But gave core dump on execution. Any reason?

Comment: Besides the point but still very relevant, use the extensionless header file version i.e iostream & cstdlib instead of iostream.h & stdlib.h, the latter is a C header file you are using in a C++ project, for this remove the .h and add a c before the header name to give you a C++ header file. The ones you are using are archaic, and though they may not spell errors in your code but on modern compilers and in the future definitely could be an issue. For a full explanation of what I mean refer this article http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but you're seeing errors about 'myheap' because the compiler was confused about earlier errors.  Fix the first error first.

About overloading operator new, there's more to it than a simple malloc.  I have an [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898920/how-might-i-overload-the-new-operator-to-allocate-memory-from-a-secondary-memor/1898960#1898960) that may help, but that was global new instead of class-specific.

Here it is cleaned up: (this compiles and runs)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A {
  static int count;
  static int heap_count;
  void* operator new(std::size_t t) {
    void* p = malloc(t);
    if (!p) throw std::bad_alloc();
    heap_count++;
    return p;
  }
  void operator delete(void *p) {
    free(p);
    heap_count--;
  }
  A() {
    count++;
  }
  ~A() {
    count--;
  }
};
int A::count = 0;
int A::heap_count = 0;

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  A a, b, c, d, e;
  auto_ptr<A> g (new A), h (new A), i (new A);

  cout << "Total: " << A::count << '\n';
  cout << "Dynamic\nHeap: " << A::heap_count << '\n';
  g.release();
  cout << "After delete g: " << A::heap_count << '\n';
  h.release();
  cout << "After delete h: " << A::heap_count << '\n';
  i.release();
  cout << "After delete i: " << A::heap_count << '\n';
  cout << "Heap: " << A::heap_count << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know, I *just* realized you were the OP on that linked question. ><

Answer (score 0):

It should be `A::myheap`.

<strike>Also, your operator new should invoke the constructor:</strike>
You're right, you just need to return the pointer to the newly allocated object.

```
void * operator new(size_t t)
{
 A *p = (A*)malloc(t);
 myheap++;
 return p;
}
```

Comment: new() also needs to return the object that was new'd (p).

Comment: Igor...I think Constructor is not called explicitely as it is called implicitely.

Comment: No! The new operator calls the ctor, your operator new overload doesn't even know the right ctor to use!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a local named `myheap` but you do have a class-scoped static variable named `myheap`. Thus you need `A::myheap`. But really, `myheap` and `x` should be private and you should have a static `getx` and static `getmyheap` public methods defined. And, of course, `x` should have a better name.

Comment: @Roger Pate: He _was_ talking about in `main` where he simply had `myheap` (instead of `A::myheap`) and that is what I was referring to. His code has since been edited which is grossly out of line as it renders answers irrelevant and leads to confusions such as this one. Note that he has left a comment to his question "After fixing `myheap` to `A::myheap` it worked" supporting my statements here.

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep,

The reason you were getting a core dump when new was not returning p is because your delete function tries to free the pointer you pass in.

Since new wasn't returning p, the value being sent to delete() is either NULL or un-initialized. Calling free with a pointer that is NULL or a random value from the stack will cause your program to crash.

Best,

Sam