# overloading operator new without overloading operator delete

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

HI All

I have the simple code below. I defined operator new for my class without operator delete.
According to `valgrind --leak-check=yes PROGRAM_NAME` I have a mismatch i.e. I am allocating using `new[]` for arrays, but I am deallocating with simple `delete` for non array. Do you know why?

Regards
AFG

```
#include<string>
#include<new>


class CA{
public:
CA(){
    std::cout << "*created CA*";
}   

~CA(){
    std::cout << "*deleted*";
}

void* operator new( std::size_t aSize ){
    std::cout << "*MY NEW*";
    void* storage = std::malloc( aSize );
    if( !storage )
    {
        std::exception ex;
        throw ex;
    }
    return storage;
}};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
CA* p = new CA();
delete p;   
return 0;
```

}

```
==2767== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==2767==    at 0x4024851: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==2767==    by 0x80488BD: main (operator_new_test.cpp:54)
==2767==  Address 0x42d3028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd
==2767==    at 0x4024F20: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==2767==    by 0x80489A4: CA::operator new(unsigned int) (operator_new_test.cpp:18)
==2767==    by 0x804887B: main (operator_new_test.cpp:53)
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but `new` should throw `std::bad_alloc` on failure.

Comment: @Steve: If only someone had [answered](http://bit.ly/b8gwX3) with a foolproof way to overload global new. :)

Answer (score 8):

Your overloaded operator `new` uses `malloc`, but then you deallocate using the normal C++ `delete` operator.  This is a classic error.  If you allocate with `malloc`, you must *always* deallocate with `free`.  If you allocate with `new`, you must *always* deallocate with `delete` (or `delete[]` in the case of arrays).

You'll need to overload the `delete` operator and have it call `free()`.

Comment: +1 -- do you ever get the feeling that we'll all be explaining this until we're very very old?

Comment: One day I'll give some important advice about life to my grandchildren: never mix `malloc` and `new`, or you'll end up regretting it some day.

Comment: I usually use the pair new/delete and new[]/delete[]. I though that since malloc is used in new this one would have been masked someway, so in my head looked like a common pair new/delete. Thanks a lot for the kind response!

Answer (score 1):

When you overload operator new, you *must* overload operator delete so you know the right deallocation function (free, in this case) is called.

There's a couple of problems with your overload as well; see [my example on overloading new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898920/how-might-i-overload-the-new-operator-to-allocate-memory-from-a-secondary-memor/1898960#1898960).  Simply replace allocate_from_some_other_source with malloc and deallocate_from_some_other_source with free.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate with `malloc` you should free with `free`.